# How to call/use a script or conf file from another folder with relative path?

Tags: linux, shell, path, scripting

I have a folder “main” contains two sub folders “common” and “scripts”.

How to call shell script or .conf file in “common” folder from “scripts” folder's shell script, without using absolute path ?

I have to call/use .conf and .sh files from “common” in “scripts” .sh file, with relative path from “main”, how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within `common/` call e.g. `bash ../scripts/myscript.sh`